# Error in discrete_colours(colours) : could not find function "discrete_colours"

Tags: r, ggplot2

In ggplot, I am trying to plot a continuous variable "CPUE" against "Year" and assigning different colors according to a categorical variable "Gear".

```
ggplot(data=datAn, aes(Year, CPUE, color=Gear))+geom_point()
```

I have suddenly been getting the following error message:

```
Error in discrete_colours(colours):could not find function "discrete_colours"
```

Not sure this is relevant but, when loading the library, I get the following:

```
Attaching package: ‘ggplot2’
The following objects are masked _by_ ‘.GlobalEnv’:
scale_colour_continuous, scale_colour_discrete, scale_colour_gradient, scale_fill_continuous,
scale_fill_discrete, scale_fill_gradient
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: This means that the ggplot2 package doesn't include this function.

Comment: But it used to work fine. Is there a way I can "reset" ggplot2. I tried uninstalling/reinstalling the package but it doesn't help.